# Meteor - Facebook Graph Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I am creating a meteor app. I successfully implemented the facebook login but now the last feature I should implement is to create a chat (involving facebook messenger) between the page(admin) and the user. It should happen through the app. Could I do that with meteor or I should use javascript. The second question, if it is not possible with meteor is how to initialize the messenger conversation, if I by using the facebook user Id which I already know from the registration. I know that there are a lot of discussions about the graph-api but I could not find anything which includes meteor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize in app deep linking to direct a user to the messenger.

```
fb-messenger://user/%s
```

the %s represents the user-id of the user who will receive the message!
Android as well as iOS will handle these requests properly.